# При запуске игры, она мгновенно закрывается (UNITY)

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Загрузил игру в google play на внутреннее тестирование. Файл .aab .Качаю с плей маркета, открываю ее, и она мгновенно закрывается. Даже не показывает стартовый экран. Без каких либо ошибок(плей маркет только предупреждение пишет чтобы отладочные символы загрузил, но это не ошибка)
Раньше я компилировал файл APK и просто кидал его на телефон - все работало отлично. В чем проблема?
[image: скрин 1]

Comment: В чем угодно - используй logcat что бы разобраться

Comment: @ValeraKvip Ошибка в logcat: `E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.MuorejoGames.ShoesIndustry-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.MuorejoGames.ShoesIndustry-1/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.MuorejoGames.ShoesIndustry-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.MuorejoGames.ShoesIndustry-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.MuorejoGames.ShoesIndustry-1/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]`

Comment: только не пойму что ей нужно. Я еще менял версию Unity с 2021 на 2020 чтобы убрать ошибку при компиляции "android.R8". Проект изначально создавался на версии 2021.

Comment: Возможно нужно добавить файлы в исключение R8 или прогуарда. Чтобы их имена не изменялись.

Comment: Вот трассировка стека из консоли Google Play, которая вызывает сбой: `at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo (com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads-lite @@ 20.5 .0: 1) `

Я делал игру на версии 2021, после этого пришлось сменить версию на 2020 LTS. Компиляция проходит без ошибок. Я удалил все активы AdMob и GooglePlayServices и все, что связано с Google и отключил все связанные скрипты, но эта ошибка при инициализации сервисов все равно появляется в Гугл Консоли, при попытке запуска игры. Я не понимаю.

Comment: Я только что нашел эти файлы в плагинах (скрин 1). Вероятно, они остались после удаления. Может быть это из-за них? Если да, то как мне узнать, какие из них можно удалить?